# DuplicateFile table ignored during MSI execution

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I have built an MSI in Installshield and I wish to copy some files from one location to another as part of the installation process. 
As the files I want copied on the target machine are files being installed by the MSI, I used the DuplicateFile table.

The purpose of the MSI is to backup and update some EXE files on a number of target machines.

I have added 3 entries into the DuplicateFile table, all much the same as below:

```
KeyFile : DUPSTMMFILE
Component: STMM (reference to component in the project)
File: xxx (reference to file in the project, under the selected component)
DestName: stmedia.q9644
DestFolder: BACKUPS
```

For the Destination Folder (BACKUPS), I have created a new entry in the Directory Table:

```
Directory : BACKUPS
Directory_Parent: INSTALLDIR
DefaultDir : BACKUPS
IsAttributes: 0
```

When I build the back I have no errors.

On running the MSI, the files are replaced I expect to be replaced, but the copies I expect to be present are not there.

When I log the output, DuplicateFiles appears not even to recognize there are entries to process.

What steps could I be missing?

```
MSI (s) (C0:90) [17:20:15:078]: Doing action: DuplicateFiles
Action 17:20:15: DuplicateFiles. Creating duplicate files
Action start 17:20:15: DuplicateFiles.
DuplicateFiles: File: Creating duplicate files,  Directory: ,  Size: 
Action ended 17:20:15: DuplicateFiles. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (C0:90) [17:20:15:078]: Doing action: BindImage
Action 17:20:15: BindImage. Binding executables
Action start 17:20:15: BindImage.
Action ended 17:20:15: BindImage. Return value 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment but I don't have the points yet.

When you mentioned the file: xxx (reference to file in the project, under the selected component) - did you use the filename or the filekey for that file from the file table?

How many more times can I say file....

The docs say to use the filekey.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368335(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It's a drop down field which is populated with the files within the component. so I selected the appropriate file from the predefined list.